# How to call a java function that has such prototype?

Tags: java, apache-commons-cli

org.apache.commons.cli  has interface like this:

`public Option.Builder type(Class<?> type)`

Sets the type of the Option.

Parameters:

```
type - the type of the Option
```

Returns:

```
this builder, to allow method chaining
```

If I want to build an option with type "int", how should I call this function?

Answer (score 4):

Try using this:

```
Options options = new Options();
options.addOption(OptionBuilder.withLongOpt("integer-option")
                      .withDescription("description")
                      .withType(Number.class)
                      .hasArg()
                      .withArgName("argname")
                      .create());
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems you are asking how to express the Class of int.

Try `int.class`.

Comment: It makes a long time I didn't talk :) I hope you are fine :)

Comment: @davidxxx Yes, I thought so, too. I am working in a different time zone for the next 4 weeks, but nice to see that you are still around. But now I have to go and do some early morning sport.

Comment: Oh it's original. Interesting matter to handle ? And more money I hope ! :p A good shape produces a good design !

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `Number.class` for `int` or `Integer`.

So just to give you an idea:

```
Options options = new Options();
options.addOption(
        OptionBuilder.withDescription("description")
        ...
        .withType(Number.class)
        ...
        .create());
```

Comment: Thanks.  Compiling passes.